# How can I take a screenshot of a whole web page?

Tags: screenshot

I have been testing various Firefox extension for screenshot grabbing, but none of them suited my needs.

Then I have found Shutter (0.86.3), and it is really nice. I use exporting to imageshack and FTP a lot.

The only thing I miss is grabbing the whole web page area (not just the part currently visible on the screen). Is there any Shutter extension for this or similar app with such a feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/) does what you want.

**Edit:**
Since screengrab is not maintained anymore, Awesome Screenshot is a good option:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/awesome-screenshot-capture-/

Comment: Actually Screengrab is EOL. "FF changes too fast and I don't have the time to maintain it anymore. Bugs have developed that I am not in a position to investigate. Therefore, Screengrab is EOL." https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/

Comment: @AvatarParto I updated the answer.

Comment: [ScreenGrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/) died and was then reborn as [ScreenGrab (fix version)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab-fix-version/)

Comment: For me with chrome and awesome screenshot the function to capture a screenshot of an area does not work.
For you?

Answer (score 15):

The GCLI no longer exists. See [answer to duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/a/589699).

---

On recent versions of Firefox, there is no need for any plugins. This capability is built into the browser.

1. In Firefox, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open the in-browser CLI. This is a command-line interface at the bottom of the browser window which lets you do all kinds of awesome stuff. (I find the `restart` option particularly useful.)
2. Type `screenshot --fullpage` (this will autocomplete, so `s` <kbd>Tab</kbd> `--f` <kbd>Tab</kbd> will work; the autocomplete is shown by grey text ahead of the cursor).

That will save the screenshot as a PNG file to your downloads folder. By default, the filename includes the date and time. You can use a different filename if you wish, simply by passing it in on the CLI: `screenshot --fullpage my_name.png`.

Comment: Is there an argument to control resolution?

Comment: If you type `screenshot --` you can then use the up and down arrow keys to scroll through the available options. I see nothing there about screen resolution, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

There is an *amazing* extension for Firefox called [[image: firefox addon icon] **pdfit**](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/pdfit/), which allows you to save any webpage you are currectly watching *entirely* (from top to buttom) in varios formats: pdf, jpg, ...

Comment: But I need all in one solution: desktop and web page screenshot tool

Comment: Why do you need an all in one? Why not best tool for different jobs?

Answer (score 3):

I use nanoshot which has its own web-capturing setting.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nanoshot/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nanoshot
```

Comment: Looks promising, but after: `Take screnshoot of a web page` it shows the image I need (long page), but there is no option to save it. There's only `[Take!]` button, which saves just the visible portion.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use google-chrome (or chromium-browser) you can have several so-called: "extensions" which will allow you to take full screenshots of almost any website.

There are restrictions on some sites, in example: you can't take a shot of your hotmail inbox or some e-shops.

I use:

Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce#

Explain and Send Screenshots
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mdddabjhelpilpnpgondfmehhcplpiin#

Webpage Screenshot
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki#

These tools are useful for taking full or partial page screenshots, make annotations, simple edit of the captured image and other features.

A screenshot of my site is placed here in order to illustrate.
[image: http://geppettvs.x10.mx]