# How to take screenshot of complete webpages?

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

I have used **shutter** and **screenshot** applications for a long time for taking screenshots.But they can only take screenshots as big as the physical screen.

Sometimes I have to take an ***screenshot of an whole webpage***,because the page can't be saved properly by the browser or I want to include pop-up's as well.This situation requires a software that can take a screenshot longer than the physical screen.

Is there any software to do this?

> Note that [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/25414/184942) question and it's answers are about webpage saving apps.They won't save pop-up's, which is essential in my case.I don't want a converter.I need an literal screenshot app or anything that could save the pop-up's as well.

And I use Mozilla Firefox, because it has really nice plugins.The solution should be working fot Firefox itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I take a screenshot of a whole web page?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25414/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-a-whole-web-page)

Comment: @landroni They won't save pop-up's, which is essential in my case.Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by pop-up, but does the [answers given here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231757/screenshot-tools-to-capture-scrolling-windows) help?

Comment: @Aditya I don't know what thing that is, but it looks like something similar to pop-up's.but it doesn't move. It is not saved as well. the specific link is [this](http://blog.mx17.net/2011/08/03/howto-root-your-xperia-x10-mini-pro-2-1-1-a-0/).

Comment: @Aditya no they don't work.shutter fails.the other does nothing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On recent versions of Firefox, there is no need for any plugins. This capability is built into the browser.

### New Method with the Mouse

Very simple: right click anywhere on the page that is not otherwise active, and select “Take Screenshot”. The popup which appears will allow you to select a region of the visible page, or the complete webpage.

### Console Method

1. In Firefox, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open the Web Developer Console. (The exact key combination may depend on your settings.)
2. Type `:screenshot --fullpage` (this will autocomplete, so `:s` <kbd>Tab</kbd> `--fullpage` will work).

That will save the screenshot as a PNG file to your downloads folder. By default, the filename includes the date and time. You can use a different filename if you wish, simply by passing it in on the CLI: `:screenshot --fullpage my_name.png`.

This will also work on pop-up windows, but each window will need to be saved individually. I know of no way to combine them into a single screenshot. (You could, of course, do that in GIMP or another image-editing tool later.)

Comment: Perfect! I hadn't expected an answer after such a long time. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me, but with little change about the 'Shortcut'. I am using the 'Firefox 36.0.4' and 'Shift+F2' was for 'Developer Console'. For the 'Browser Console', shortcut was 'Ctrl + Shift + J'. Just in case if it helps someone!!

Comment: That may have been a plugin altering default behaviour, @VinodTigadi. I'm not sure.

Comment: Ya, Probably. Because, I checked at 4-5 Ubuntu machines at my work place. All of them had the shortcut 'Ctrl + Shift + J'. Anyways, thanks for your quick reply :-)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+J, for me, brings up a Browser Console for debugging, which is a different thing to the in-browser CLI, a simple command line for controlling the browser itself, rather than examining the page currently opened.

Comment: @RegisteredUser. Not sure whether you were notified of my edits to this question for the latest Firefox.

Comment: @TRiG I have noticed this change in firefox at some point. Thanks for updating the answer. PS: You might want to keep the old answer as well, with a note that it's outdated, and adding the new answer on top.

Answer (score 3):

Here a list of applications that you can use from terminal:

- wkhtmltopdf [(source)](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

wkhtmltopdf is a command line utility that converts html to pdf using webkit rendering engine.

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

- wkhtmltoimage [(source)](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html)

The wkhtmltoimage utility shall take the screenshot of a given url, and save it as a png image. It uses the webkit rendering engine.

Download :
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list

**Usage :**

To use the wkthmltoimage utility simple run the command from terminal, giving the url and the name for the image file.

```
$ ./wkhtmltoimage-amd64 http://www.google.com google.png
```

It will create google.png in home directory with the screenshot of www.google.com

**Other options :**

wkhtmltoimage provides many options to customise the screenshot. Some examples are as follows :

Quality - Controls the quality/compression of the generation image. Default is 94

```
$ ./wkhtmltoimage-amd64 --quality 50 http://www.google.com google.png
```

Disable images

```
$ ./wkhtmltoimage-amd64 --no-images http://www.google.com google.png
```

Disable javascript

```
$ ./wkhtmltoimage-amd64 --disable-javascript http://www.google.com google.png
```

Crop the screenshot

```
$ ./wkhtmltoimage-amd64 --crop-h 300 --crop-w 300 --crop-x 0 --crop-y 0 http://www.google.com googl
```

- cutycapt [(source)](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)

Cutycapt is a utility to take the screenshot of a url, using the webkit rendering engine and save it to an image file.

Install

```
sudo apt-get install subversion libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev g++ cutycapt
```

**Usage**
To use cutycapt, simply run the command from the terminal, providing the url and the name for the output file.

```
$ cutycapt --url=http://www.google.com/ --out=google.png
```

It will create google.png file in home directory which would have the screenshot of www.google.com

- khtml2png [(source)](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/index.php)

khtml2png uses the konqueror rendering engine to create screenshots of web pages.

Download

```
http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=download
```

Install

To install khtml2png, the program has to be compiled and build on the system.

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs4-dev zlib1g-dev g++ cmake
Extract the khtml2png archive.
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall (this will create a deb file and install it , so that it can easily uninstalled later)
```

**Usage**
To use khtml2png run the program from commandline providing the url and other options.

```
$ khtml2png2 --width 800 --height 600 http://www.google.com/ google.png
```

This would create a google.png in home directory with the screenshot of www.google.com.

- PyWebShot [(source)](https://github.com/coderholic/PyWebShot)

Pywebshot uses python bindings embedded mozilla ( http://www.mozilla.org/unix/gtk-embedding.html )

Install

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtkmozembed

Download pywebshot from https://github.com/coderholic/PyWebShot
```

Usage :

```
$ python pywebshot.py www.google.com -t 1024x768&lt;br /&gt;<br />Loading www.google.com... saved as www.google.com.png
```

It should create a www.google.com.png in the directory which has the screenshot of size 1024 x 768.

Comment: please check the commands.are they specific for amd64 system? I use i386 system.

Comment: No they are not specific for amd64. give them a try

Answer (score 2):

I tried [Awsome Screenshot: Screen Capture Annotate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-screen/nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj?hl=en) - A Chrome Plugin. It worked pretty well for me. Captured the Pop-Ups(jQuery Based)[Not the Alerts], Full Page Capture and worked with HTTPS too!! Great tool.

Comment: Works great for Chrome!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who came here looking for a CLI option:
There is no need for any other tool, latest version of both chrome and firefox have inbuilt abilities.

**Chrome**

```
/path/to/chrome --headless --screenshot="img.png" "www.stackoverflow.com"
```

**FireFox**

```
/path/to/firefox -screenshot img.png www.stackoverflow.com
```

That's it.

Comment: If you get _Open multiple tabs is only supported when remote debugging is enabled._ make sure you actually typed the `=` after `--screenshot`

Answer (score 1):

On firefox you can use a addon called [Awsome Screenshot Capture plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/awesome-screenshot-capture-/)

Comment: Oh I did not see that you needed the pop-up window, I don't know whether it can do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Chrome, you can use [Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) extension which supports full page screenshots. Note that it may sometimes not work with HTTPS enabled pages.